# "Firewall" for X applications

Tags: linux, security, privacy

I don't want proprietary Skype directly accessing my Xorg server. I've already taken measures securing filesystem, network, processes/IPC, but there still a plenty of spying possibilities using X alone.

Currently I use Xvfb+x11vnc+vncviewer, but it is not convenient: copy&paste works poor, no systram icon&notifications.

I want the firewall to stand in middle between X server and the application and allow the applications:

- to create normal windows, systray icons, show notifications on other desktops;

but deny:

- Locking session;
- Interacting with clipboard when I'm not asking;
- Captuing input not explicitly directed to the application's window;
- Enumerating other windows;
- Being notified of activity/inactivity;
- Setting configuration like with `xrandr` or `xinput`;

It should feel something like VirtualBox's seamless mode, but without VirtualBox.

/* [xorg](/questions/tagged/xorg)  or [x](/questions/tagged/x)*/

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/126321/how-to-make-xephyr-to-hide-its-background-rootless-mode-like-in-cygwin-x